# Paperclip fails on Heroku with Papercrop and ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Rails 5 app where users (devise) can upload a profile image and crop it if need be (Using Paperclip and Papercrop). Everything works on local. No problem at all.

When I push it to Heroku and try to crop I get the following error: (Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError)

I have looked at all SO questions out there and there are no replies that seem to work. Anyone had any luck solving this before?

As mentioned - Locally it runs great. On Heroku it fails. Could it be an update required to ImageMagick on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something related to Heroku's environment.

Did you try that link? https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Upgrade-Imagemagick-On-Heroku

It also can be that you cannot write on Heroku machine file system, maybe your image stills in memory and tries to save when you crop it, where are you saving it?

Reference:
[Paperclipped on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096588/paperclipped-on-heroku)